# Reactjs: returning children with cloneElement

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to this and following a tutorial.  I've actually copied the code from the starter files but the children do now show in the React devtools, hence not rendering.  The components are fine and I can render them individually. PhotoGrid doesn't show as a child of Main that's all. This is the code:

Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

const Main = React.createClass({
    render() {
        const props = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>
                    <Link to="/">Reduxstagram</Link>
                </h1>

                { React.cloneElement(props.children, props) }
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default Main;
```

App.js

```
    import React from 'react';

import { render } from 'react-dom';


// Import css
import css from './styles/style.styl';

// Import Components
import Main from './components/Main';
import Single from './components/Single';
import PhotoGrid from './components/PhotoGrid';

// import react router deps
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';


render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={PhotoGrid}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ props.children }` will render the children of the component (from your question I see no need to use `React.cloneElement`). See modified code below:

```
const Main = React.createClass({
    render() {
        const props = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>
                    <Link to="/">Reduxstagram</Link>
                </h1>

                { props.children }
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

**Sidenote**

React-router has recently been updated to v4. You may want to use the new router ([docs for react-router-4](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/)).